# Application defined error in range property procedure, what is causing the error?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm interested in why why following line `("Sheets("Euro_usd").Columns("A").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = EURO_USD.t_date")` causes an

> "Application defined or object defined error"

Replacing the code with the equivalent : `Sheets("Euro_USD").Cells(rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = EURO_USD.t_date` makes the error to dissapear.

Why is the error appearing? Does it have to do with that the end(xldown) for columns property is already occupied in the stack( not sure on terminology ) and thus the new request is generating an error?

```
Private Sub run() ' run the whole operation

Dim HTTP_Req As Object: Set HTTP_Req = New HTTP_Req
Dim EURO_USD As Object: Set EURO_USD = New EURO_USD


If Sheets("EURO_USD").Columns("A").End(xlDown).Value = DateValue(EURO_USD.t_date) Then
    Debug.Print "Date already exist"
    Else
    Sheets("Euro_usd").Columns("A").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = EURO_USD.t_date <-- Error here!

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Find the last row and then add the value. You may want to see [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba) Also to check if a date is in a column or not, you can use `Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf()`

Answer (score 1):

If column A is empty, this statement tries to write in the row after the maximum row in the sheet which is impossible. Check it by printing `Sheets("Euro_usd").Columns("A").End(xlDown).Row`. It is probably equal to `Sheets("Euro_usd").Rows.Count` (which gives you the maximum row number).

The second statement (`xlUp`) will result in the first row if column A is empty thus writing the value in the second row (`Offset(1,0)`).

Comment: Well, the thing is that Column A is not empty... thus writing shets("Euro_usd").Columns("A").end(xldown).row returns 3

Comment: What is the value and type of EURO_USD.t_date when you write this value?

Comment: Also try if you can set Sheets("Euro_usd").Columns("A").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = Date. All this just for trying to find out which part of the statement raises the error.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time help me out. the = date statement works correctly.